# A new entity was found through the relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine2

Пишу тесты для приложения на symfony, в нем есть консольная команда которая запускает множество методов, которые берут сущности из базы, циклично отправляют запросы на сторонние API, и в результате записывают некие данные назад в базу. Когда я запускал эту команду то все работало, в тестах же я вызываю эти методы по отдельности, а сущности создаю перед тестими в DataFixtures а уже в естах вытягиваю так:

```
self::$campaign = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')
            ->getRepository(Campaign::class)
            ->findOneBy(['name' => 'Test campaign for sync 1']);
```

тест:

```
public function testCreateCampaign(): void
    {
        $fbCampaign = self::$campaignService->create(self::$campaign);
        $this->assertInstanceOf(FCampaign::class, $fbCampaign);
        $this->assertEquals(self::$campaign->getUser()->getCompany()->getName() . '/Test campaign for sync 1', $fbCampaign->getData()[CampaignFields::NAME]);
        $this->assertEquals(true, $this->seeInDatabase(CampaignChannels::class, ['facebookCampaignId' => $fbCampaign->getData()[CampaignFields::ID]]));
    }
```

но тут уже не работает а выдаёт ошибки типа:

> Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException : A new entity was found
>   through the relationship
>   'CampaignBundle\Entity\CampaignChannels#campaign' that was not
>   configured to cascade persist operations for entity:
>   CampaignBundle\Entity\Campaign@000000003d9037ca000000005eb33dc7. To
>   solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you
>   cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   'CampaignBundle\Entity\Campaign#__toString()' to get a clue.

```
/**
 * @var CampaignChannels[]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CampaignBundle\Entity\CampaignChannels", mappedBy="campaign")
 */
private $channels;



   /**
     * @var Campaign
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CampaignBundle\Entity\Campaign", inversedBy="channels")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="campaign_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $campaign;
```

метод который тестируется:

```
public function create(Campaign $campaign): FCampaign
{
    $fbCampaign = new FCampaign(null, 'act_' . $this->facebook->getAccountId());
    $fbCampaign->setData([
        CampaignFields::NAME => $this->getCampaignName($campaign),
        CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE => CampaignObjectiveValues::LINK_CLICKS
    ]);

    try {
        $fbCampaign->create([
            FCampaign::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => FCampaign::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->saveErrors($ex, null, $campaign->getId());
        throw $ex;
    }

    $channel = $campaign->getFacebookChannel();
    $channel->setFacebookCampaignId($fbCampaign->getData()[CampaignFields::ID]);
    $channel->setLastSync(time());
    $this->objectManager->persist($channel);
    $this->objectManager->flush();

    return $fbCampaign;
}
```

*Ещё один ньюанс - до того как я создавал мои сущности в DataFixtures я их создавал прямо в методе setUpBeforeClass(), сохранял в статические переменные и оттуда вызывал - и все работало, но после того как перенес в  DataFixtures работать перестало, хотя сами методы что я тестирую никак не редактировал*

Comment: Покажите связь Campaign и CampaignChannels, а так же CampaignChannels и Campaign

Comment: persist просто добавляет набор изменений в UnitOfWork. Если изменений действительно не было - не будет никаких запросов. Однако, судя по всему, изменения всё же были. Вам нужно внимательно трассировать выполнение кода, чтобы найти модификацию.

Comment: В том то и дело что вызывается только класс теста, и в перевом же тесте, коотрый вызывает метод в коотром есть только один persist возникает ошибка

Comment: Мы не видим тут полного кода, чтобы точно поставить диагноз. Вероятно, Вы используете какие-то моки. Возникает ощущение, что findX возвращает не смердженную сущность(новую либо десериализованную). У Вас используется какое-либо кеширование?

Comment: Кеш есть но перед тестами он очищается. Моки не используются, я беру сущность прямо из базы

Comment: Вопрос в том, очищается ли он **между** тестами. Попробуйте добавить `objectManager->clear()` в `setUp`

Comment: тоже не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Вы не вызвали persist для вновь созданной сущности `Campaign`.

> To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

Варианта решения 2:

- найти сущность и вызвать `$em->persist($campaign)` для неё.
- настроить каскадное выполнение `persist`, если сущность была создана, как зависимость другой сущности, которой Вы `persist` вызываете.

Comment: В том то и дело что я на создаю сущность Campaign а беру её из базы, беру из неё сущность CampaignChannels, изменяю и сохраняю её. Campaign уже существует и не изменяется.

Comment: UnitOfWork так не считает. Вероятно, что-то изменяется неявно.

Comment: Значит нужно пересохранить Campaign, а потом все связанные с ней поля? это же будут сотни запросов

Answer (score 0):

Измените связь:

```
/**
 * @var CampaignChannels[]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CampaignBundle\Entity\CampaignChannels", mappedBy="campaign", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $channels;
```

Comment: Это приводит к ошибке с сущностями связанными с Campaign, он их тоже пытается пересохранить, в результате так можно дойти до того что будут пересохраняться все существующие сущности

Comment: В случае, если Вы проставите это в связанных таблицах, ORM сама будет пересохранять связанные данные(если это требуется) и у Вас не будет ошибки.

Comment: Но у меня ORM почему то вместо обновления пытается вставлять новые записи. Например Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException : An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO users (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, full_name, stripe_id, google_account_id, order_type, updated, created, deleted_at, company_id, currency_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ...